# Getting status from object returns different value compared to var_dump

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, state

I have this piece of code:

```
public function getAllOpenOrders() {
     $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
                $collection->getSelect()->join( array('orders'=> sales_flat_order), 'orders.entity_id = main_table.order_id', array('orders.status'));
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('orders.status',
                    array( 
                        array('eq' => 'pending'),
                        array('eq' => 'processing'),
                    )
                );
}
```

When I `var_dump` the first object in a `foreach` loop is see the object has the following data.

```
["status"]=> string(7) "pending"
```

But when I do `echo $object->getStatus();` it returns a different value. It returns `Ordered` when I echo and `string(7) "Ordered"` when I `var_dump` it.

What am I missing, or what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The foreach loop in my template file

```
<?php $orders = $this->getAllOpenOrders(); ?>

<?php foreach($orders as $order): ?>
     <?php var_dump($order->getStatus()); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can u please share code inside loo[

Comment: @AmitBera sure, just added the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `getStatus()` of order **items** (this is what your collection returns!) is [an actual method](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php#L521-L524) and not a magic getter:

```
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->getStatusName($this->getStatusId());
}
```